# OctoberCMS backend list value

Tags: octobercms

Is there a way to replace list value from 1 to Yes in backend form/list?

**Example**
Database table **entries**

```
id - auto_increment
title - varchar
date - date
time - time
text - text
public - INT (1)
```

Now i created list in Builder which looks like this

[image: List]

So how would i replace **1** with **Yes**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to create a partial for the column
https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-partial

Modify your **myplugin/models/themodel/columns.yaml** file for the public field

```
public:
    type: partial
    path: ~/plugins/yourname/myplugin/models/themodel/_content_column.htm
```

The content **_content_column.htm** file will be

```
<?php if ($record->public==1): ?>
 Yes
<?php else: ?>
No
<?php endif; ?>
```

or

```
<?php if ($value==1): ?>
 Yes
<?php else: ?>
No
<?php endif; ?>
```

$value is the default cell value, $record is the model used for the cell

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for partial in this particular case. It can be easily done in **Builder**.

1. Navigate to your **plugin**
2. Select **model**
3. Open **list** manager
4. Change column type to **Switch**

[Switch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qY3GU.png)

It will display Yes/No for you automatically depending on column value (1/0)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add 'context' attribute in columns.yaml file.

```
public:
    label: Public
    context:
        1: Yes
        0: No
```