# i want to change Status column - with color in CMS october in columns.yaml

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, october-form-controller, october-partial

i want to change Status column - with color in CMS october in columns.yaml ...

how i add this :

```
<div class="control-list">
    <table class="table data">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 150px"><span>Status</span></th>
                <th class="active sort-asc"><a href="/">Title</a></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody> 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="oc-icon-circle text-success">
                        Approved
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>The sun is shining</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <span class="oc-icon-circle text-danger">
                        Cancelled
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>The weather is sweet here</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

How can I add such a thing into my system model?

Comment: can you share what efforts did you make, we can guide you

Comment: https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/list - like that in CMS october - Status column

Comment: try to use this -> https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/lists#column-partial

Comment: i see it look good but how i can do that , i cant see that on database                  status:
        label: Status
        type: group
        conditions: status in (:filtered)
        options:
            pending: Pending
            active: Active
            closed: Closed

Comment: define your status values in your model as static variable hardcoded as they may be just like 4-5 status, and use them in partial to check it out

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OctoberCMS backend list value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701741/octobercms-backend-list-value)

Answer (score 1):

**Entire row** (easier)

You can apply a class to the entire row overwriting `listInjectRowClass` in your controller and return the name of one of the classes [listed in the docs](https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/list), for example:

```php
public function listInjectRowClass($model, $definition)
{
    switch ($model->status) {
        case Order::STATUS_NEW:
            return 'new';
            break;

        case Order::STATUS_PREPARING:
            return 'processing';
            break;

        case Order::STATUS_PREPARED:
            return 'processing';
            break;

        case Order::STATUS_SHIPPED:
            return 'frozen';
            break;

        case Order::STATUS_DELIVERED:
            return 'positive';
            break;

        case Order::STATUS_WITHDRAWN:
            return 'positive';
            break;
    }
}
```

This will result in something like this:

[image]

**Just one column of the row**

This is a little more tricky, basically you have to [use a partial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvNcO.jpg) for rendering the column.

In your `columns.yaml`

```yaml
content:
    type: partial
    path: ~/plugins/acme/blog/models/comments/_content_column.htm
```

And in the partial file `_content_column.htm` you need to have something like this:

```html
<span class="<?= $record->column_status_class ?>">
   <?= $value ?>
</span>
```

where, as the docs say:

`$value` is the default cell value

`$record` is the model used for the cell

So, for this example, the model need a function called `getColumnStatusClassAttribute` which will return the proper class name.